# jms Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED and Transactional

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

What is the difference between the boolean flag in create session `createQueueSession` and `createTopicSession` that indicates if the session is transacted or not and `Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED` which looks like acknowledgment mode , but java docs points that it is not:

```
SESSION_TRANSACTED

public static final int SESSION_TRANSACTED
This value is returned from the method getAcknowledgeMode if the session is transacted. If a Session is transacted, the acknowledgement mode is ignored.
```

When I  call (e.g)

```
createQueueSession(false, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
```

It throws `javax.jms.JMSException: Incorrect acknowledge mode specified.` So is there a difference?

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: No, just tested this with different vendors and looks like they interpreter this in different ways.I should test it with glassfish as this is the reference server to see what will happen there.But on ActiveMQ it works with `createSession(false, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);`